# Recursive variable template specialization (and MSVC behaviour)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variable-templates

Given the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/qjh7Kh1ed):

```cpp
template <typename...> struct list{};

template <typename> list<> foo{};

template <typename H, typename... Ts>
list<H, decltype(foo<list<Ts...>>)> foo<list<H, Ts...>>{};
```

what is the type of `foo<list<int, double>>`?

I'm asking this because MSVC (v19.37) behaves here differently from all the other compilers I've tested this with (namely, gcc 13, clang 16, and icx 2023.2). While the other compilers use the recursive specialization in `decltype` (and so the type for them is `list<int, list<double, list<>>>`), MSVC doesn't (thus it gives `list<int, list<>>`).

The questions obviously are:

1. Is this code correct (let's say, according to the C++20 standard, for certainty) and the type in question well-defined?
2. If so, which compiler is right?

Comment: Is there a function `main` that goes with this? How are you determining the type a given compiler uses?

Comment: @tbxfreeware, yes there is, in the godbolt example (click the link above). I simply use std::is_same there, but any other way would work too.

Comment: Sorry. I did not check the link. I copied the GodBolt code, and ran it with MSVC, getting the same answer you did (i.e., 1). Unfortunately, however, your question is above my pay grade. I have no explanation for you.

Comment: Works with recursion on struct [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pb7vdxzv4).

Comment: @Jarod42, of course it does, MSVC would've been in all sorts of troubles if it didn't :-) The question is about variable templates specifically.

Comment: Trying to narrow down the issue... I suspect MSVC bug.

Comment: Do you really need `list<int, list<double, list<>>>` as opposed to `list<int, double>`?